# How to control contents in a content view with a button in another content view in .Net Maui

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui, winui

I'm practicing .Net Maui by making a Todo List App and now I'm wondering how to change the main page's content view by tapping the buttons on the bottom bar. I defined both the bottom bar and the page views as content views because I don't know how to insert a content page into an existing content page, and I want to customize the bottom bar.
The Todo List App is unfinished, I only wrote one page.

[The main Todo List App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tURoc.png)

And the file structure is:

[The file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyFfg.png)

I've defined four functions in the bottom bar user content, but I don't know how to implement them.

The whole project is on the GitHub: [GitHub Link](https://github.com/Seanwanq/MauiTodoApp). I really need your help.

I have searched through the Internet and didn't find any practical solution. But I do think that this is a realizable feature.

Here's the code.

The bottom bar:

> BottomBar.xaml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiTodoApp.Views.Contents.BottomBar">
    <Border StrokeThickness="0"
                    BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                    Margin="10, 5, 10, 10">
        <Border.StrokeShape>
            <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="10"/>
        </Border.StrokeShape>
        <Grid Margin="20, 0, 20, 0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Page1Clicked"
                                      NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>

                <Border HeightRequest="50"
                        WidthRequest="50"
                        BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
                        StrokeThickness="0"
                        >
                    <Border.StrokeShape>
                        <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="5"/>
                    </Border.StrokeShape>
                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <Label Text="1" FontSize="30"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Page2Clicked"
                                      NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>

                <Border HeightRequest="50"
                        WidthRequest="50"
                        BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
                        StrokeThickness="0"
                        >
                    <Border.StrokeShape>
                        <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="5"/>
                    </Border.StrokeShape>
                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <Label Text="2" FontSize="30"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Page3Clicked"
                                      NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>

                <Border HeightRequest="50"
                        WidthRequest="50"
                        BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
                        StrokeThickness="0"
                        >
                    <Border.StrokeShape>
                        <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="5"/>
                    </Border.StrokeShape>
                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <Label Text="3" FontSize="30"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Column="3">
                <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Page4Clicked"
                                      NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>

                <Border HeightRequest="50"
                        WidthRequest="50"
                        BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
                        StrokeThickness="0"
                        >
                    <Border.StrokeShape>
                        <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="5"/>
                    </Border.StrokeShape>
                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <Label Text="4" FontSize="30"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ContentView>
```

> BottomBar.xaml.cs

```cs
namespace MauiTodoApp.Views.Contents;

public partial class BottomBar : ContentView
{
    public BottomBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Page1Clicked(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void Page2Clicked(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Page3Clicked(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Page4Clicked(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

The first page:

> FirstPage.xaml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:Contents="clr-namespace:MauiTodoApp.Views.Contents"
             x:Class="MauiTodoApp.Views.Pages.FirstPage">
    <Grid Background="#e5e7eb">
        <Grid Margin="10, 0, 10, 0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Label Text="Today's Tasks"
                   Margin="10, 10, 10, 10"
                   Padding="0, 40, 0, 0"
                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   FontSize="30"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   />
            </Grid>
            <ScrollView Grid.Row="1" Margin="10, 0, 10, 0">
                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1"  >
                    <Contents:TasksContent/>
                    <Contents:TasksContent/>
                    <Contents:TasksContent/>
                    <Contents:TasksContent/>
                    <Contents:TasksContent/>

                    <Grid HeightRequest="90"></Grid>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

The main page:

> TodoMainPage.xaml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiTodoApp.Views.TodoMainPage"
             xmlns:Pages="clr-namespace:MauiTodoApp.Views.Pages"
             xmlns:contents="clr-namespace:MauiTodoApp.Views.Contents"
             Title="TodoMainPage">
    <Grid IgnoreSafeArea="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" ZIndex="0" x:Name="MainPageView">
            <Pages:FirstPage Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" ZIndex="0"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid  Grid.Row="1" ZIndex="1">
            <contents:BottomBar/>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Please do NOT post code as images

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can try the solution in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Shell` to achieve your need:

> I'm wondering how to change the main page's content view by tapping the buttons on the bottom bar.

AppShell.xaml:

```
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiTodoApp.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MauiTodoApp.Views.Pages">

     <TabBar>
        <ShellContent Title="FirstPage"
                     ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:FirstPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="SecondPage"
                     ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:SecondPage}" />
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

Note that FirstPage is `ContentPage`:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:Contents="clr-namespace:MauiTodoApp.Views.Contents"
             x:Class="MauiTodoApp.Views.Pages.FirstPage">

           ...

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do (if you don't want to use Shell) is to have a list of ViewModels in MainViewModel, and then bind a ContentView to the one which you are presenting using converter, something like this:

```
<Grid >
   <ContentView Content="{Binding SelectedPageVM , Converter= 
   {StaticResource ViewModelToViewConverter}}" 
   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
</Grid>
```

Then have some custom navigation (on the top or bottom), which would hold buttons created based on the ViewModels list. Selecting buttons in navigation would inform MainViewModel, and new (selected) ViewModel would be presented.
Converter might look something like this:

```
public class ViewModelToViewConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var viewModelConcreteType = value.GetType();
            var viewFullName = viewModelConcreteType.FullName.Replace("ViewModel", "View");
            var viewType = Type.GetType(viewFullName);
            return Activator.CreateInstance(viewType);                

        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In this example, Views and ViewModels are following naming rule (ex. LoginView/LoginViewModel). Also, it is important to say that you should register views and viewmodels in ServiceCollection.